# Cannot add an object to array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, cocoa, nsarray

I have the following code and am getting a strange error

```
 PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"SchoolSpecificData"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        NSMutableArray *data = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        [data addObjectsFromArray:objects];

        NSLog(@"Objects: %d", data.count);

        pickerData = [data valueForKey:@"schoolFullName"];
        NSLog(@"Picker data:%d",pickerData.count);
        NSMutableArray *testarray =[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:@"Other"];
        [pickerData addObjectsFromArray:testarray];

        NSLog(@"Picker data again:%d",pickerData.count);
        self.SchoolPicker.dataSource = self;
        self.SchoolPicker.delegate = self;
    }];
```

As you can see earlier in the block I addedobjects to an a mutable array and that worked fine but for some reason it dosen't work with the pickerData Array. This array is a property of my class and is defined as a NSMutableArray. Any ideas on why this might be happening? I also tried just adding the object but it gave the same error.

Here is the error:

```
[2965:202451] -[__NSArrayI addObjectsFromArray:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7aee6360
```

Comment: I don't see any error messages, output, or a description of what's failing.

Comment: But based on what seems to be your general problem, odds are that either 1) you're operating on a nil pointer somewhere, or 2) you've managed to create two separate instances of the "same" object.

Comment: pickerData = [data valueForKey:@"schoolFullName"]; This doesn't say that pickerData is NSmutableArray. And without NSMutableArray how can you add/delete any element?

Comment: Right that is because as i stated in my question pickerData is a property of my class that is a NSMutableArray. That is why I am confused

Comment: Do you know the difference between the type on a pointer and the type of an object????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following line is the culprit

```
 pickerData = [data valueForKey:@"schoolFullName"];
```

the above is returning an immutable array.

Try this

```
 pickerData = [[data valueForKey:@"schoolFullName"]mutableCopy];
```

**Update**

Suggested Refactoring

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"SchoolSpecificData"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        pickerData = [NSMutableArray array];
        //TODO: Need validations + capturing strong self inside block is a bad idea:)
        [pickerData addObjectsFromArray:[objects valueForKey:@"schoolFullName"]];
        [pickerData addObject:@"Other"]; 
        //You can set the datasource & delegate outside the block & reload the picker once pickerData is filled. 
        self.SchoolPicker.dataSource = self;
        self.SchoolPicker.delegate = self;
    }];
```

Comment: Or [data valueForKey:@"schoolFullName"] can be added to pickerData, as well I guess

Comment: @DebanjanChakraborty Yes. In that case, you need to have the memory location created in advance (before adding the value) for pickerData.

Comment: Why not just reverse the add and add the immutable data to the (already-)mutable array with `[testArray addObjectsFromArray:pickerData]`?

Comment: @RobP,updated the answer. With out changing the order of the objects and impl added bit of refactoring.

Comment: you can add "Other" at Index 0 with addObject:AtIndex:, to match the original code's ordering. But this new code looks cleaner to me, yes. I'd eliminate the variable `schoolnames` for readability and just inline `[pickerData addObjectsFromArray:objects[@"schoolFullName"]]` but that's just a style preference.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be

```
[pickerData addObject:[data valueForKey:@"schoolFullName"]];
```

instead of

```
pickerData = [data valueForKey:@"schoolFullName"];
```